# two RewriteRules with www redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a multiple language website, that uses subdirectories from the root ('/en' for english and '/es' for spanish) for each specific language.  Each redirect appends a get variable to the URL, and hides it using a 'P' flag for proxy.  My current htaccess file for the spanish subfolder is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1?l=es [P,R=301,L]
```

The problem is that I also want to append the 'www' to the domain if it was left off.  The proxy redirect does not show the 'www.'  Is it possible to place a rewriterule before that final one that will append the www, and then still process the final one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary, that your `www.` rewrite is solved via the proxy method? I would recommend a regular 301 redirect if the `www.` is missing. Many URLs mapping to the same app will just cause session/cookie issuse (read [no-www](http://no-www.org/faq.php)).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1?l=es [P,R=301,L]
```